# What is PostgreSQL syntax for complex array literals? (e.g. circle[])

Tags: postgresql

The PostgreSQL docs [state](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) that, though some literals have special syntax, generic syntax for literal values looks like `type 'data'`, `'data'::type`, or `CAST('data' AS type)`. For instance, one could write the integer 16 as `16` or as `'16'::int`. Dollar-quoting is also allowed, so `$$16$$:int` works as well.

For some types, such as `circle`, the generic syntax is (as far as I can tell) the *only* way to write a literal. Four syntaxes are [listed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-geometric.html#DATATYPE-CIRCLE) for circle: `<(x, y), r>`, `((x, y), r)`, `(x, y), r`, and `x, y, r`; however, none of these seem to work plain:

```
y=> create table t (c circle);
CREATE TABLE

y=> insert into t (c) values ( <(1,2),3> );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<"
LINE 1: insert into t (c) values ( <(1,2),3> );
                                   ^

y=> insert into t (c) values ( ((1,2),3) );
ERROR:  column "c" is of type circle but expression is of type record
LINE 1: insert into t (c) values ( ((1,2),3) );
                                   ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

y=> insert into t (c) values ( (1,2),3 );
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: insert into t (c) values ( (1,2),3 );
                                         ^

y=> insert into t (c) values ( 1,2,3 );
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: insert into t (c) values ( 1,2,3 );
                                     ^
```

On the contrary, using the generic syntax works fine:

```
y=> insert into t (c) values ( '1,2,3' );
INSERT 0 1

y=> select c from t;
     c
-----------
 <(1,2),3>
```

Also documented is the [array syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT), which is comma-delimited and curly-enclosed. So the range 1-5 may be written, for instance, as `'{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}'::int[]`.

Unfortunately, the array syntax does not seem to support values specified with the generic syntax: `$${ 1 }$$::int[]` is accepted, but `$${ '1'::int }::int[]` is rejected, as is `$${ '1' }::int[]`.

Because array literal syntax does not accept generic-form syntax for elements, and because generic syntax seems to be the only way to write a circle literal, it appears that it is impossible to write a circle literal in PostgreSQL.

```
y=> select $${ }$$::circle[];
 circle
--------
 {}
(1 row)

y=> select $${ '<(1, 2), 3>'::circle }$$::circle[];
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type circle: "'<(1"
LINE 1: select $${ '<(1, 2), 3>'::circle }$$::circle[];
```

Is this indeed the case?

---

Note: yes, it's crucial that I want to write a `circle[]` *literal*. The reason is that my use-case is for specifying values in prepared statements in a PostgreSQL client, and, as the PostgreSQL protocol documentation [says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY) (emphasis mine):

> Parameter data types can be specified by OID; if not given, the parser **attempts to infer the data types in the same way as it would do for untyped literal string constants**.

This means that, for instance, `ARRAY[ '<(1,2),3>'::circle ]` is not a valid solution, as it does not use literal syntax.

Comment: It's `'<(1,2),3>'::circle` - also with the other 3 formats for `data`, and the other two styles of specifying the type of the literal (which is what goes between `'` or `$$` delimiters). See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: Extrapolating that to array syntax, you'd use `'{<(1,2),3>, <(4,5),6>}'::circle[]`

Comment: What's wrong with `array[circle('(1, 2), 3'), circle('(3, 4), 5')]`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That doesn't work as a parameter value for a prepared statement, like with `$1::circle[]`, does it?

Comment: @Bergi that seems like it should work, but in fact doesn't. Try with a plan `SELECT`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That works in contexts where expressions are allowed, but is not a literal.

Comment: Well, that **is** a literal (a constant value). But you seem to be looking for a string literal that can be cast to the correct type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed. (I usually consider the term "literal" to be a syntactic classification, but perhaps this is not common)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the solution is simple: escape the commas!

```
y=> select '{ <(1\,2)\,3>, <(4\,5)\,6> }'::circle[];
          circle
---------------------------
 {"<(1,2),3>","<(4,5),6>"}
(1 row)
```

Also an option is to double-quote the elements:

```
y=> select '{ "<(1,2),3>", "<(4,5),6>" }'::circle[];
          circle
---------------------------
 {"<(1,2),3>","<(4,5),6>"}
(1 row)
```

Credit [to sehrope on Github](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2594#issuecomment-896026771) for telling me this. Quote from the [relevant part of the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#:%7E:text=as%20a%20NULL.-,As%20shown%20previously,-%2C%20when%20writing%20an):

> [...] when writing an array value you can use double quotes around any individual array element. You must do so if the element value would otherwise confuse the array-value parser. For example, elements containing curly braces, commas [...], double quotes, backslashes, [etc,] must be double-quoted. [...] Alternatively, you can avoid quotes and use backslash-escaping to protect all data characters that would otherwise be taken as array syntax.